# How to assign the lead owner data to contact in a trigger?

Tags: apex, trigger, account, leads, before-trigger

I'm trying to create a trigger that creates an account and contact when the lead status is changed to a given value. The contact value needs to come from the Lead Owner User. How can I achieve that?

```
if(Trigger.isInsert){
    List<Account> accountList = new List<Account>();
    List<Contact> contactList = new List<Contact>();
    List<User> leadOwner = new List<User>();

    for (Lead lead : Trigger.new) {
        System.debug('lead: ' + lead);

        if(lead.Status == 'Confirmed Contact'){
            Account account = new Account(Name = lead.Company, cnpj__c = lead.cnpj__c);
            accountList.add(account);

            Contact contact = new Contact(
                FirstName = //need information from the owner lead
                LastName = //need information from the owner lead
                Email = //need information from the owner lead
                Phone = //need information from the owner lead
                AccountId = account.Id
            );
            contactList.add(contact);    
        }
    }
    if(accountList.size() > 0 && contactList.size() > 0){      
        insert accountList;    
        insert contactList; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write that something like this.

First, we'll initialize some variables.

```
Set<Id> ownerIds = new Set<Id>();
Account[] newAccounts = new Account[0];
Contact[] newContacts = new Contact[0];
Lead[] leadsToConvert = new Lead[0];
```

Then, we'll find all records that have their status set to Confirmed Contact.

```
for(Lead record: Trigger.new) {
  if(record.Status == 'Confirmed Contact') {
    ownerIds.add(record.OwnerId);
    leadsToConvert.add(record);
  }
}
```

Next, we need the owner's details for later.

```
Map<Id, User> owners = new Map<Id, User>([
  SELECT FirstName, LastName, Email, Phone
  FROM User WHERE Id = :ownerIds
]);
```

And now we'll create the Account records.

```
for(Lead record: leadsToConvert) {
  newAccounts.add(
    new Account(
      Name=record.Company,
      cnpj__c=record.cnpj__c
    )
  );
}
insert newAccounts;
```

Note that we have to insert the accounts before we can use the Account Id. Now, we create the contacts using the owner information.

```
for(Lead record: leadsToConvert) {
  User owner = owners.get(record.OwnerId);
  newContacts.add(
    new Contact(
      FirstName=owner.FirstName,
      LastName=owner.LastName,
      Email=owner.Email,
      Phone=owner.Phone,
      AccountId=newAccounts.remove(0).Id
    )
  );
}
insert newContacts;
```

The last trick, `newAccounts.remove(0).Id` works because the accounts were added in the same order as the contacts, so we can use `newAccounts` as a FIFO (first in, first out) buffer.

This code doesn't address things like Queues or any real error handling. You will most likely need to make changes to the code.